# CXF JAX-WS with custom XmlOutputFactory + WSDLGetOutInterceptor writes prolog twice

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

With CXF 3.0.1, I defined a custom XmlOutputFactory to get rid of annoying invalid characters:

```
<bean id="invalidCharacterReplacingXmlOutputFactory" class="a.b.c.InvalidCharacterReplacingXmlOutputFactory"/> 
<!-- that extends com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory -->

<jaxws:endpoint id="myWebService" implementorClass="a.b.c.MyService"
        implementor="#Mybean" address="/myService">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="javax.xml..XMLOutputFactory">
                <ref bean="invalidCharacterReplacingXmlOutputFactory"/>
            </entry>
        </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Everything worked at this point, except when I tried to get the WSDL, it failed with:

```
Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done.
```

Indeed, the StaxOutputInterceptor(cxf-core) sets the flag FORCE_START_DOCUMENT to true when a xmlOutputFactory is defined, and writes the prolog when the flag is set to true:

```
public static XMLOutputFactory getXMLOutputFactory(Message m) throws Fault {
 Object o = m.getContextualProperty(XMLOutputFactory.class.getName());
        if (o instanceof XMLOutputFactory) {
            m.put(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.DISABLE_OUTPUTSTREAM_OPTIMIZATION,
                        Boolean.TRUE);
            m.put(FORCE_START_DOCUMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
            return (XMLOutputFactory)o;
        }
```

The WSDLGetOutInterceptor (cxf-frontend) then tries to write the prolog and throws an exception. This clearly was a cxf problem to me, so I searched through new versions of cxf to see if that was fixed.

After a bit of research, I found a commit from the cxf git repository on the WSDLGetOutInterceptor class, whose message is:

> Write the prolog only if it hasn't already been written

this can be found here: [https://github.com/apache/cxf/commit/25f0eb7f955a84baf6c3b634ff316cb831a2acfa ]

But while looking at the change something stroke me:

```
-            StaxUtils.writeNode(doc, writer, true);
+            StaxUtils.writeDocument(doc, writer, true,
+                                    !MessageUtils.getContextualBoolean(message, 
+                                                                       StaxOutInterceptor.FORCE_START_DOCUMENT, 
+                                                                       false));
```

Looking at the signature of the 2 methods, we can find:

```
public static void writeNode(Node n, XMLStreamWriter writer, boolean repairing) 
public static void writeDocument(Document d, XMLStreamWriter writer, boolean writeProlog,
                                     boolean repairing)
```

So, after the commit, and until now (I checked with many versions), the boolean repairing which was always true before now depends on `!MessageUtils.getContextualBoolean(message, StaxOutInterceptor.FORCE_START_DOCUMENT, false))`, and the boolean writeProlog is always true, while it really seems like it is related to the original problem.

I'm kind of tired so I maybe missed something. If anyone could take a look a it or/and give me a solution that doesn't depend on the cxf version, I would really appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

The issue is indeed a CXF bug, which will be fixed in versions 3.2.0, 3.1.8, and 3.0.11.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7087